# How to ensure only one copy of the application is running?

Tags: c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing multiple process instances on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964391/preventing-multiple-process-instances-on-linux)

I have multi-threaded application which can be run as a deamon process or one time with input parameters.

I want to ensure that if the application is running as a deamon process then, user should not be allowed to run this again.

EDIT:After you all suggested to go for flocks, I tried it and put it in server. I know have weird problem, when the servers are bounced, they delete all the files, including lock file :(. How now ?

Comment: On Linux this is done via a `lockfile`.

Comment: @aix I just realised that and made a edit.Thanks anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964391/preventing-multiple-process-instances-on-linux

Comment: @Cicada good point, so it is like i have write a file in the current directory when the process is started and should'nt allow the application to run if the file already exist ?

Comment: Is it actually a single process with multiple threads, or is it multiple cooperating processes? The answer depends on that.

Comment: @Cicada the application can be run from any directory, since the /bin is added to the PATH variable. which directory to check for the lock file?

Comment: @tbert : it is single process with multiple threads.

Comment: @Cicada Depends. Is it a per-user application? Then `~`. Else I'd go for `/tmp` (or `/var/run` maybe).

Comment: in that case the user should have permission to that directory , if he doesnt have permission then I should not start the application?

Comment: Also this raise another question in mind, what if the application terminates abruptly before deleting the file? In such, the application wouldn't start even when no application is running.

Comment: @dicaprio apparently this got re-edited after I answered (or I just misread); in this case, a lock file is the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to bind to a port (could be unix domain, in a "private" directory) **Only one process can bind to a port**, so if the port is bound, the process is running. If the process exits, the kernel automatically closes the filedescriptor. It does cost your process a (unused?) filedescriptor. Normally a daemon process would need some listen socket anyway.

Comment: +1, this is definitely a clean approach, especially if the daemon already needs to bind a socket, which it probably does.

Comment: This is absolutely the best approach (and not PIDs, file locks, tmp files and all other kinds of nonsense posted here)

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [file locks](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock).  Upon starting the process, you can open a file, lock it, and check for a value (e.g. size of file).  If it's not desired value, the process can exit.  If desired value, change the file to an undesired value.

Comment: Cant I just check if the file exist ? The process which created the file will delete it when it terminates. This raise another question in mind, what if interupt occur? How to handle it?

Comment: Yeah just checking existence of file is probably enough.  You can create file using [tmpfile](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tmpfile).  If your program crashes, the file automatically deletes.

Comment: Actually, thinking of it, I don't think opening is enough.  If two process call open() at the same time, race conditions might occur inside the kernel.  It's safer not to assume.

Comment: tmpfile, I didnt know this before :( , Thank you I learnt something.

Comment: Actually I'm an idiot.  If you make the file using tmpfile, you won't know the file name, so each time tmpfile is called it'll create a new file.  I don't think there's a solution to this problem if your process crashes.  Firefox and git routinely run file lock problems.

Comment: Files created by `tmpfile` usually *do not have a name*. So it's worse than just not knowing the name...

Comment: Also, in general using the existence of a file as a lock is bad because it will not be removed if the process is killed.

Comment: @R.. your point is correct, now I'm facing a wired problem after I implemented lockfile. I notice that some process when they are bounced they run "rm -rf" and this file get deleted.

Comment: Yes, lock files are a very bad approach.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented similar thing by using shell scripts to start and stop the daemon.

In the start script before the exe call look if this exe is still running. If it finds it is still running then new process is not started.

Comment: Thanks this is definitely a good idea. I first see if we can implement it in the process itself, if not this idea works too.

Comment: This is not a good idea. It's error-prone (searching running processes is not robust and can give false positives) and race-prone (it will allow two daemons started at almost the same time to both run).

Comment: I agree it is not the most robust way. But it suited to my requirements as only one user had the permissions to start the daemon.