# what's the difference between the double click and console open

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to open one application instance only once, so I just do like 
`NSArray *apps = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.my.app"];` in main.m
When I open the app from the console, the count of apps array will be 0. However, when I double click on the app, it will be 1
So can anyone tell me what's the difference between the double click and console open? or give me another way to check if there's already one instance running?

Comment: You might want to ask a separate question specifically about how to ensure only one process of your program is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that command queries the workspace and that is updated 'delayed'

when the app is started from finder, it is launched **via** the `NSWorkspace`, so the workspace is updated right away

when the app is started via the console/xcode it is **not started via** `NSWorkspace`, so that class returns 0 at the start. After the `NSApplication` of your process is up, the workspace is informed and its 1.

=> it is always correct in `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification`

---

so either wait for NSApplication to start and THEN kill it (like you do now, but later)

OR

see [Preventing multiple process instances on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964391/preventing-multiple-process-instances-on-linux) for a way to do it without cocoa

OR

you look at launchd which can do this :) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

Comment: If there's was an instance running, I do not want the new `NSApplication` be run. What should I do?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to work through launchd instead of creating a pidfile somewhere?

Comment: The app could be opened by double click and called in my code. I want to make sure that there's only one instance running. And thank you for the answer about the difference.

Comment: either you wait with your check till appDidFinishLaunching and kill one there, OR you go with the pid way I posted

Comment: OR you look at launchd which can do this :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code.  `getBSDProcessList` function will return `NSArray` of running process.[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772594/944634)

```
static int GetBSDProcessList(kinfo_proc **procList, size_t *procCount)
// Returns a list of all BSD processes on the system.  This routine
// allocates the list and puts it in *procList and a count of the
// number of entries in *procCount.  You are responsible for freeing
// this list (use "free" from System framework).
// On success, the function returns 0.
// On error, the function returns a BSD errno value.
{
    int                 err;
    kinfo_proc *        result;
    bool                done;
    static const int    name[] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0 };
    // Declaring name as const requires us to cast it when passing it to
    // sysctl because the prototype doesn't include the const modifier.
    size_t              length;

    //    assert( procList != NULL);
    //    assert(*procList == NULL);
    //    assert(procCount != NULL);

    *procCount = 0;

    // We start by calling sysctl with result == NULL and length == 0.
    // That will succeed, and set length to the appropriate length.
    // We then allocate a buffer of that size and call sysctl again
    // with that buffer.  If that succeeds, we're done.  If that fails
    // with ENOMEM, we have to throw away our buffer and loop.  Note
    // that the loop causes use to call sysctl with NULL again; this
    // is necessary because the ENOMEM failure case sets length to
    // the amount of data returned, not the amount of data that
    // could have been returned.

    result = NULL;
    done = false;
    do {
        assert(result == NULL);

        // Call sysctl with a NULL buffer.

        length = 0;
        err = sysctl( (int *) name, (sizeof(name) / sizeof(*name)) - 1,
                     NULL, &length,
                     NULL, 0);
        if (err == -1) {
            err = errno;
        }

        // Allocate an appropriately sized buffer based on the results
        // from the previous call.

        if (err == 0) {
            result = malloc(length);
            if (result == NULL) {
                err = ENOMEM;
            }
        }

        // Call sysctl again with the new buffer.  If we get an ENOMEM
        // error, toss away our buffer and start again.

        if (err == 0) {
            err = sysctl( (int *) name, (sizeof(name) / sizeof(*name)) - 1,
                         result, &length,
                         NULL, 0);
            if (err == -1) {
                err = errno;
            }
            if (err == 0) {
                done = true;
            } else if (err == ENOMEM) {
                assert(result != NULL);
                free(result);
                result = NULL;
                err = 0;
            }
        }
    } while (err == 0 && ! done);

    // Clean up and establish post conditions.

    if (err != 0 && result != NULL) {
        free(result);
        result = NULL;
    }
    *procList = result;
    if (err == 0) {
        *procCount = length / sizeof(kinfo_proc);
    }

    assert( (err == 0) == (*procList != NULL) );

    return err;
}

+ (NSArray*)getBSDProcessList
{
    NSMutableArray *ret = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    kinfo_proc *mylist;
    size_t mycount = 0;
    mylist = (kinfo_proc *)malloc(sizeof(kinfo_proc));
    GetBSDProcessList(&mylist, &mycount);
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < mycount; k++) {
        kinfo_proc *proc = NULL;
        proc = &mylist[k];
        NSString *fullName = [[self infoForPID:proc->kp_proc.p_pid] objectForKey:(id)kCFBundleNameKey];
        NSLog(@"fullName %@", fullName);
        if (fullName != nil) 
        {
            [ret addObject:fullName];
        }                                        
    }
    free(mylist);  
    return ret;
}

+ (NSDictionary *)infoForPID:(pid_t)pid 
{
    NSDictionary *ret = nil;
    ProcessSerialNumber psn = { kNoProcess, kNoProcess };
    if (GetProcessForPID(pid, &psn) == noErr) {
        CFDictionaryRef cfDict = ProcessInformationCopyDictionary(&psn,kProcessDictionaryIncludeAllInformationMask); 
        ret = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)cfDict];
        CFRelease(cfDict);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Take a look at [Technical Q&A QA1123](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#qa/qa2001/qa1123.html) (Getting List of All Processes on Mac OS X)

Comment: You didn't answer the question. What's the difference between these two situations? Why does the code work in one but not the other?

Comment: @Parag Bafna thank you for your code Parag, but I do not wanna all of the processes, that's too heavy for my code

Comment: + with the hint to use NSWorkspace you have just repeated non-working code

Comment: @Daniel Gao What do you mean by "too heavy"?

Comment: @Parag Bafna sorry, i cannot access stackoverflow these days, and i had done what i want to do, thanks for your sharing