# limiting User from executing a specific process in duplicate

Tags: linux, process, ulimit

I'm trying to figure out a way to limit a specific process from running in duplicate.

I have a process (named ops_tool) that is executed with a functional user.
This user is accessible to multiple users and the process is executed on demand.
If one person executes and another one executes, it's a mess.
Reports are generated incorrectly, etc.

what I want is to limit the execution of the process. I could use ulimit to limit the quantity of the processes but that would limit in general and I want to specifically limit that process to 1.

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing multiple process instances on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964391/preventing-multiple-process-instances-on-linux)

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150778/prevent-a-second-instance-of-my-software-from-starting

Comment: Thanks Robert for pointing a direction.
Î will check and see if it can be a solution or not.